# Single line if statement in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swift4

How would one convert the following to Swift from Objective-C?

```
if (myVar) return;
```

Swift does not use parentheses around the conditional, however the following code  gives an error.

```
if myVar return
```

Comment: Unlike Objective C, braces are mandatory while using if statements in Swift. The reason behind this is to make the code safer.

Comment: you have to add the braces `{}` for all branches, but the parenthesis are optional `()`, you can keep them if you'd like to.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In Swift the braces aren't optional like they were in Objective-C (C). The parens on the other hand are optional. Examples:

Valid Swift:

```
if someCondition {
    // stuff
}

if (someCondition) {
    // stuff
}
```

Invalid Swift:

```
if someCondition 
    // one liner

if (someCondition)
    // one liner
```

This design decision eliminates an entire class of bugs that can come from improperly using an if statement without braces like the following case, where it might not always be clear that `something`'s value will be changed conditionally, but `somethingElse`'s value will change every time.

```
Bool something = true
Bool somethingElse = true

if (anUnrelatedCondition) 
    something = false
    somethingElse = false

print something // outputs true
print somethingElse // outputs false
```

Comment: One example of a widely publicized bug which is related to this, is [Apple's SSL/TLS bug](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html), while Swift was in development. I sometimes wonder if this design decision was made because of that, or if it's just coincidental. It's an interesting detail of Swift, since it's very uncommon for "C like" languages to enforce a coding style.

Comment: Apple's SSL/TLS bug - doesn't indicate that single line If's are the problem. It clearly shows that CMD+V should not use "Key-delay" and "key-repeat" setting of keyboard and should paste only once. Try copying one line of text and press CMD+V a little longer than usual. That's unless, developer purposely put two consecutive "goto fail;" assuming to work in a single if block, to make sure that if in case the control pointer does not obey the first time, repeating a second time would help. "You still here ???? I have already told you to goto fail.... GOTO FAIL this instant !!!"

Comment: You can't put parenthesis around `if let` statements.

Answer (score 65):

Well as the other guys also explained that braces are a must in swift. But for simplicity one can always do something like:

```
let a = -5

// if the condition is true then doThis() gets called else doThat() gets called
a >= 0 ? doThis(): doThat()

func doThis() {
    println("Do This")
}

func doThat() {
    println("Do That")
}
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use new Nil-Coalescing Operator, since Swift 3 in case when you need just set default value in case of if fails:

```
let someValue = someOptional ?? ""
```

In case if someOptional is `false`, this operator assign "" to someValue

```
var dataDesc = (value == 7) ? "equal to 7" : "not equal to 7"
```

Answer (score 16):

One-line `if`, one-line `while` and one-line `for` are considered a bad style by many developers because they are less readable and allegedly a source of many errors.

Swift solved the conundrum by forbidding one-line flow control statements; the braces are non-optional...

```
if someCondition {
     // stuff
}
```

Of course, you can still do

```
if someCondition { return }
```

There are also implementation reasons. Having the parentheses around the condition as optional makes the parsing much harder. Enforcing braces simplifies parsing again.

Comment: "Alleged" is about right. With conventions such as consistent use of Allman braces and indentation, it was already very preventable.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple solution I used in my projects.

**Swift 4+**

```
isManageCardTnCSelected ?
      (checkbox.isSelected = true) : (checkbox.isSelected = false)

var selected: Bool = isManageCardTnCSelected ?
      checkbox.isSelected = true : checkbox.isSelected = false
```

**Swift 3+**

```
var retunString = (state == "OFF") ? "securityOn" : "securityOff"
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution for **Swift 3+**

```
isMyVar ? someAction() : ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Easy One line Solution

```
var isSeller = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isRole") as? String == "ROLE_SELLER") ? true : false
```

Comment: I think swift conventions says to not use parenthesis on if statements

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Easy Solution

```
let exercise = (segcExercise.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? "GymLover" : (segcExercise.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) ? "Occasionally" : "No Way"

//MARK:- outPut   // Occasionally
```

[image]